# Kafka Serde case class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to create a store of `StoreBuilder[KeyValueStore[String, TimedGenericRecord]]` with `case class TimedGenericRecord(record: GenericRecord, timestamp: Long)`.

Therefore I need to create a `Serde[TimedGenericRecord]`.

For the `GenericRecord`, Kafka already provides a Serde, the same for `Long`.
Is there a way to create a Serde for the case class and use those provides Serdes?
Because in the current setup, it seems you can only deserialize a complete `byte[]` which does not allow you to reuse the provided Serdes.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from an answer from the Confluent Slack channel:

> In your case, you know that `long` is serialized to 8 bytes -- thus,
>   you copy `inputBytes[0]` to `inputBytes[inputBytes.lenght - 8]` into a
>   new byte array that you give to `AvroDeserializer` and the copy the
>   last 8 byte and give to `LongDeserializer`. On the serialization path,
>   you serialize avro and long, and than concatenate both into one byte
>   array that you return.